# Benifits of using java interfaces in jax-rs web services?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I am very new to this world of web services. And I am currently exploring Apache CXF based JAX-RS web services. Well while talking to some of my seniors who has a pretty good idea of web services, he told me that t is always a good practice to expose an interface as a web service rather than the implementation class. But I don't think I fully understand the benefits of such a approach. Can someone explain me why should a interface based approach be better than a normal approach??

Also, Can someone point me to a link which can show me how a interface based jax-rs web service is built from scratch rather than just changing a existing one to an interface form.!!

Comment: Your inteface defines the contract and your underlying implementation can change/overridden. As long as your interfce doesnt change the clients know they need not change, ideally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the base in OOD. This is good practice because you separate design from implementation eg.

> Now you have WebServices based on JAX-RS. In the future you can have
>   to extend your system of JAX-WS implementation. Then you don't have to
>   create one new class, but you create another implementation based on
>   the same design (polymorphic).

When you create loose coupling system, you can create flexible application, easy to tested and extend.

With the links:
http://dhruba.name/2008/12/08/rest-service-example-using-cxf-22-jax-rs-10-jaxb-and-spring/